# google compute engine files for HA LAMP are not there for download?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-compute-engine

I found this guide in the google documentation for the cloud platform.

https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/high-availability-lamp-stack-on-google-compute-engine

although the files it asks you to download, are not found when the link is clicked?

anyone know where they actually are?

Comment: Reported the problem. This is being fixed.

Comment: since it simply refers us back to the cloud.google.com documentation, is there another HA article other than the second one you also removed the files for??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately we deprecated this sample application as it was focused on migrating applications around maintenance windows.

Now that we have live migration and transparent maintenance windows, developers no longer need to move components of their application around zones due to impeding maintenance. Additionally, Cloud SQL now supports MySQL wire protocol which significantly reduces the complexities of managing applications for high availability.

In the future we may develop a new application, but it will be greatly simplified since we can offload load balancing to Compute Engine load balancer and persistency to Cloud Datastore and Cloud SQL.

Comment: I am just trying to get a grasp of the platform. I have been using it since December although would like to setup one of those demo HA systems. My goals are keeping our e-commerce platform stable and highly available. Thank you for your reply!